# list index out of range, python

Tags: python

I get an Error **list index out of range** when I'm trying to split a big list in to an array with arrays in it.

I have no idea why this is happening.

the end result of this code should be an array with arrays in it. So that i later can call for example val[5] and get 10 values.

I'm able to print `val` if the `print` statement is inside the `for` loop. And the code is working as it should. But if I move the `print` statement outside the `for` loop I get the `Index out of range error`.

```
import sys
import numpy as np 
from numpy import array, random, dot

def vectorizeImages(filename):
    file_object = open(filename)
    lines = file_object.read().split()

    #array to save all values that is digets.
    strings = []
    values = []
    images = []
    val = []
    test=[]

    #loop that checks if the position in the list contains a digit.
    #If it does it will save the digit to the value-array.
    for i in lines:
        if i.isdigit():
            strings.append(i)

    #Converting all the strings to ints.
    strings = list(map(int, strings))

    #deviding every value in the array by 32
    for i in strings:
        a = i 
        values.append(a)

    #splits large list into smaller lists and ads a 1 

    for i in range(len(values)):
        a = []
        for j in range(400): 
            a.append(values[i*400+j]) #ERROR:list index out of range
        a.append(1)
        val.append(a)
```

Comment: If `i` already takes values up to the full length of `values` then very quickly `i*400` is going to exceed the length of the list... that's before you add `j` on top.

Comment: move the `a=[]` to outside of the for loop. You are creating a blank list each time you iterate the range length of values. Also, don't use range(len()) but instead use `for index, value in enumerate(values)`

Comment: The error message explains what's wrong in plain English. Try putting the line `print(len(values), i*400+j)` just before the line where you get the error, and you'll see that the second value printed is equal to or larger than the list length.

Comment: @Swift I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP wants. You're not going to get IndexError from appending to `a`, the index issue comes from `values`. It's not unreasonable to clear `a` on each iteration of an outer loop.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Inserting useful `print` statements is the first step.  Also, I don't know that anyone will dig through this to repair your actual problem.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.

Comment: @roganjosh hence why it is a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Swift but a comment that is unrelated to the issue and could well be _against_ the intended behaviour

Comment: And that's for the op to decide, not you

Comment: @Swift If you wish to present something as a command on what the OP needs to do (move this out of the loop), which I strongly suspect is not the issue, you don't have an exclusive conversation privilege between yourself and the OP. Everything here is open to peer review and I think your command here is counterproductive.

Comment: You can have all the opinions you want my friend.

Comment: @pault, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to solve my problem (also improved my python skills)

```
def readImages(images):

lines = open(images).read().split()
images = []

values = [float(i)/32.0 for i in lines if i.isdigit()]

for i in range(len(values) / 400):
    a = [values[i * 400 + j] for j in range(400)]
    images.append(a)

return np.array(images)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here: `a.append(values[i*400+j])`.

When `i` = 0, then you populate `a` and you end up with 400 elements. You do the full loop if your have at least 400 elements.

But at some point, you will ask for more elements than what you have in `values`, and then it fails because you loop and the biggest element you ask is `len(values) * 400 - 1` which is obviously greater than your list size.